# How to get MD5 checksum of newest files in directory?

Tags: linux, shell, md5, checksum

I use the following code here to get all the files within my hard drive to be put into a new text file. Is there a way to modify this code to just get files added after a certain date? (For example, August 28th 2021 and onwards)

```
find -type f -exec md5sum "{}" + > checklist.txt
```

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Comparing-Timestamps-1

Answer (score 1):

Try using `xargs` with `find` to apply `md5sum` to each file that `find` finds.

For example, this command will give you the md5sum for each file in the current directory modified since Aug 15, 2021:

```
find . -type f -newermt '2021-08-15' -print0 | xargs -0 md5sum
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to find the md5 based on creation time rather than date modified?

Comment: Yes, see revision I made to the answer.